# Manipulating Excel in Visual Basic

Tags: excel

i have a excel file ( csv actually) that I need to delete the first row and then reformat the first column.
I have never worked with excel in Visual basic. Any help would be appreciated. or at least pointer in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: If you aren't using VB *inside* Excel, manipulating a text file in VB is pretty simple.  Plan to open the file, read it line-by-line and write out each reprocessed line (or not, in the case of the first row).

Experience tells me to tell you to write it to a NEW file and only update the original when you're sure the whole process completed.

Comment: In Excel, turn on the macro recorder, and do the steps you outline above.  Then you can stop the recorder and take a look at the code.  Then, you should be able to piece together some sort of code that works, then post it here for more directed help. (Ah, I'm referring to if VBA is okay)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to deleting a row and reformating it is to use the ClearContent function.

It is a pretty simple VBA command that looks like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G37").ClearContents
   ' "Sheet1" is the name of your Tab in this scenario
```

What this does is that it clears the content of A1 to G37 without actually deleting the cells. This means that Data Validation and Conditional Formatting rules remain intact.

Let's say you want to clear Row 1 Entirely, you would make the code look like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:XFD1").ClearContents
   'XFD1 in this situation is the last column of an excel sheet. You could just clear A1:Z1 to clear 26 column worth of text.
```

I don't know if this is what you are looking for as your request gives very little information :P Hopefully this will help you out.

If this works out for you, you can attach a trigger to this function. Such as a Macro button, or a condition. I can walk you through the process if this solution works for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. What I want to do is DELETE row 1 and move the rows up. THEN reformat COULUMN A to a specific date format. This is also done in Visual Basic 2012. Not VBA